# How to Change the productname of clickonce deployment after first install?

Tags: winforms, deployment, visual-studio-2005, clickonce

We have an application on pilot implementation using clickonce to deliver fast updates. We have even automated the build proces with nant and we can control every step of the building of the deploy package.

This pilot, we delivered with the productname "PRODUCT TITLE (PILOT)", but now, we want to upgrade all our pilot users to the production build.
We changed the productname of the build script and it was all good for the new users, it correctly displayed the product name, but the users who had previous versions installed where seeing on their shortcuts and update prompts, the "(PILOT)" version of the productname.

What we have tried so far:

- Uninstall the App: the install prompt appears with the old productname (no good)
- Uninstall and clean the local settings/Apps and local setting/aplication data : same thing.

The system is built on visual studio 2005 (FW 2.0) and the app is winforms. Client PCs are on XP SP3

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling the app and installing fresh SHOULD work.

Are you uninstalling while logged on to the machine as the normal user on that machine, or as an administrator?

If you're not logging on as the user you're trying to support, there may be your issue.  ClickOnce applications are installed in a sandbox per user, so if you and I share the machine, and we both install an app via ClickOnce, if you upgrade, that does not affect me at all.  The same goes with uninstalling.

At any rate, we had s similar situation here.  Our end users don't normally have access to the Add/Remove Programs because of group policy settings, so our admins were logging in with their admin accounts and uninstalling, but when e logged in as the user, the app was still there.  We ended up having to change our group policy settings and uninstalling while logged in as the user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I'm trying on a pilot user's machine, under they session. I'm going to revisit (again) all the steps, maybe I missed some place that needs to be modified.

Comment: This IS the answer: As i suspected, was another thing in the wich was keeping the app to update correctly. Someone modified the unc share to the updates for the new users but not for the old ones.

Comment: Good deal!  I'm glad you got it figured out!